# how to split datatable into multiple datatable based on row count in C#

Tags: c#

how to split **datatable** into multiple **datatable** based on row count in `C#` .Please give the suggestion to me 
.

```
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("", con);
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", specializationId);
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", userId);
                    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@counter", counter);
                    da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Paging?

Comment: 1. Either format or remove that query as no one will be able to read it as 1 huge line. 2. Ask a question instead of just a title and code dump

Answer (score 1):

You know how to use database paging? Then what is the problem? Just fill a `DataTable`, store this `DataTable` in a `List<DataTable>` or `DataSet` and then select the next row-set into another `DataTable` and add that to the collection.

If you have filled already a big `DataTable` with all rows and you want to split it into multiple `DataTable`s, this code does it:

```
int tableSize = 100;               // for example
DataSet allTables = new DataSet(); // or List<DataTable>

for (int i = 0; i < bigTable.Rows.Count; i += tableSize)
{
    DataTable tbl = bigTable.Clone(); // same columns, empty
    for (int ii = 0; ii < tableSize; ii++)
    {
        if (i + ii == bigTable.Rows.Count) break;
        tbl.ImportRow(bigTable.Rows[i + ii]);
    }

    allTables.Tables.Add(tbl);
}
```

Comment: I want each table of 20 rows. If the datatable row count is 100 then it splits into 5 tables

Comment: @GirishPatil: well, then change `tableSize = 100` to `tableSize = 20`

Comment: can you please look into one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688229/how-to-split-data-table-into-multiple-tables-with-adding-1-minute-delay) related to it?